# Web page for blog post demonstration

Tags: beginner, html5, css3

I am a CSS and HTML5 newbie. I'm creating a minimal web page to demonstrate something in a blog post. So although it doesn't need to look *great*, I would like it to make sure it's solid. It has no errors or warnings when I use the W3C validator.

```css
.navigation  {
   float: left;
}
.content  {
   float: left;
}
table  {
   border:1px solid #000;
   border-spacing: 0px;
   background-color: #EEE;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
thead  {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
th  {
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding: 4px;
}
td  {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 4px;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
.liked  {
   background-color: #CD0;
}
.unliked  {
   background-color: white;
}
.color_like  {
   text-align: center;
}
.color_name  {
   text-align: right;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navigation">
        <form id="search_colors_form_id" method="get" action="/colorliker/">
            <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text"/>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LvwycpyDh8xhACAh9DaqTUaPh6YkqoAe' />
            <input id="id_pic_submit_button" type="submit" value="Search for color"/><BR>
            (Requires two or more characters)
        </form>
        <BR>Searching for "<CODE>gr</CODE>":<UL>
            <LI>gray</LI>
            <LI>green</LI>
        </UL>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_body">
            <H1>Color Likenatorizer</H1>

            <TABLE><TR>
                <TH>Title</TH>
                <TH>Favorite?</TH>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">aqua</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_12/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">black</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_13/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">blue</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_14/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">fuchsia</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="liked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_15/">Yes</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">gray</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_16/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">green</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_17/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">lime</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_18/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">maroon</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_19/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">navy</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_20/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">olive</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_21/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">orange</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_22/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">purple</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_23/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">red</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_24/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">silver</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_25/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">teal</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_26/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">white</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_27/">No</A></TD>
            </TR><TR>
                <TD CLASS="color_name">yellow</TD>
                    <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_28/">No</A></TD>
            </TR></TABLE>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No more need for Code Pan or JSFiddle when we have [Stack Snippets](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/stack-snippets-are-live-click-here-for-your-sandbox?cb=1) See the little present I edited into your post!

Comment: @janos: Thanks for the tip. Updated as a (displaying) stack snippet. I also updated it to pure html. I accidentally put some Django tags in there.

Comment: Nicely done! And welcome to Code Review!

Comment: You should stick to either lower or upper case in your HTML tags, don't mix them. I'm not sure if current conventions recommend lower over upper, though.

Comment: I haven't used W3C validator in a while because I haven't built any websites recently, but you can run your site through that as much as you want, I would also test in major browsers that it shows up the way you want it to, IE (all versions after IE8), FireFox, Chrome and Safari at the least.

Comment: @IvoCoumans as far as I know current convention is lowercase.

Comment: @Malachi Yes, current *convention* is lowercase. Only with XHTML is it a **requirement**.

Comment: Why go from hex colors to `background-color: white;`? **Consistency is key.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of your HTML is off and a little bit odd to me

```
<div class="navigation">
    <form id="search_colors_form_id" method="get" action="/colorliker/">
        <input type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text"/>
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LvwycpyDh8xhACAh9DaqTUaPh6YkqoAe' />
        <input id="id_pic_submit_button" type="submit" value="Search for color"/><BR>
        (Requires two or more characters)
    </form>
    <BR>Searching for "<CODE>gr</CODE>":<UL>
        <LI>gray</LI>
        <LI>green</LI>
    </UL>
</div>
```

1. Stay consistent with your Capitalization, don't use SCREAMCASE for HTML tags
2. Be consistent with your tag terminations, always terminate tags

   ```
   <br/>
   ```
3. When you comment your code, make sure that you use Comment Tags

   ```
   <!-- (Requires two or more characters) -->
   ```

   This might not be a comment, if it isn't then see point #4
4. Text should always be housed in a tag

   ```
   <p> Searching for "<code>gr</code>": </p>
   ```
5. Structure of HTML tags, your `<ul>` tag should not follow all that other stuff, it should look like this

   ```
   <ul>
       <li>gray</li>
       <li>green</li>
   </ul>
   ```

---

You have a div inside of a div and they aren't used for anything.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_body">
```

these could easily be one div like this

```
<div class="content content_body">
```

because both are surrounding the same piece of HTML.

---

The way that you wrote your table bothers me, it's not standard formatting, this isn't something that will cause errors but it is harder to read

```
<TABLE><TR>
    <TH>Title</TH>
    <TH>Favorite?</TH>
</TR><TR>
    <TD CLASS="color_name">aqua</TD>
        <TD CLASS="unliked"><A HREF="/colorliker/like_color_12/">No</A></TD>
</TR><TR>
```

This is how I would write the same HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Favorite?</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td CLASS="color_name">aqua</td>
        <td CLASS="unliked">
            <a HREF="/colorliker/like_color_12/">No</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- ... -->
<table>
```

There are different variations, but most are very similar to this format

Comment: Thank you. Easy and obvious tips. Surprised that the open and close `tr`s shouldn't be on the same line. I've posted updated source in a new answer.

Comment: it's more of a readability thing. before Highspeed internet they used to take out all the whitespace in HTML/JS/CSS so that it would take up less space, it wasn't readable at all, sometimes they still do it with large JS files, the process is call minify I think.